# How to make a gradient background color full screen and blend between the appbar and body in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

how to make a gradient background color full screen and blend between the appbar and body, so the colors look merged and don't look disconnected between the colors in the appbar and body.
this is the view:

[image]

this is my code:

```
    return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Title"),
      elevation: 0,
      flexibleSpace: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
            colors: [
              Color.fromRGBO(205, 193, 255, 1.0),
              Color.fromARGB(255, 252, 99, 99),
              Color.fromARGB(255, 173, 41, 1),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    body: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
          colors: [
            Color.fromRGBO(205, 193, 255, 1.0),
            Color.fromARGB(255, 252, 99, 99),
            Color.fromARGB(255, 173, 41, 1),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
      child: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text("bla bla bla"),
            Text("bla bla bla"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: then do not use separate decorations for `appBar` and `body`, instead make them transparent and wrap `Scaffold` with `DecoratedBox`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution one:** set `appbar` background and `scaffold` background to transparent and set extendBodyBehindAppBar true and set top padding manually:

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Text('test'),
      ),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topLeft,
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
            colors: [
              Color.fromRGBO(205, 193, 255, 1.0),
              Color.fromARGB(255, 252, 99, 99),
              Color.fromARGB(255, 173, 41, 1),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
        10,
        AppBar().preferredSize.height +
            MediaQuery.of(context).viewPadding.top,
        10,
        0),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Text("bla bla bla"),
              Text("bla bla bla"),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

**Solution two:** use `DecoratedBox` and set `appbar` and `scaffold` background to transparent:

```
DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.centerRight,
          colors: [
            Color.fromRGBO(205, 193, 255, 1.0),
            Color.fromARGB(255, 252, 99, 99),
            Color.fromARGB(255, 173, 41, 1),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: AppBar(
          leading: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          elevation: 0,
          title: Text('test'),
        ),
        body: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
          child: Center(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Text("bla bla bla"),
                Text("bla bla bla"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

[image]